# Opaque pop up window

Tags: html, css, popupwindow

I have found this code from google, and it is working fine but the pop up window is transparent and I want to make it opaque. (I know that the pop up window is transparent because if I zoom in the browser I can see the pop up window overlapping with the background content and the background content is visible)

Here is the link to code:

[popup window](https://jsfiddle.net/bijay_ps/ppqct0dg/1/)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Popup div with disabled background</TITLE>
    <style>
        .ontop {
            z-index: 9999;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;             
            background-color: #cccccc;
            color: #aaaaaa;
            opacity: .8;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
        }
        #popup {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            /* To align popup window at the center of screen*/
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -100px;
            margin-left: -150px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pop(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
        }
        function hide(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
        }
        //To detect escape button
        document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
                hide('popDiv');
            }
        };
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div id="popDiv" class="ontop">
        <table border="1" id="popup">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    This is can be used as a popup window
                    <br></br>
                    Click Close OR escape button to close it
                    <a href="#" onClick="hide('popDiv')">Close</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <CENTER>
        <h3>
            Simple popup div with disabled background
        </h3>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" onClick="pop('popDiv')">Click here to open a popup div</a>
    </CENTER>
</BODY>
```

For some reason, I am not sure of, I couldn't make this code work in jsfiddle, but I have used the same code in one html file with  tags for css and it is working fine.

Kindly help.

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark left of the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, but only if the Javascript comes before your onclick-handlers in the source code.

So you need to change the following setting in JSFiddle (the second dropdown must be set to "No wrap - in `<head>`":

[image]

In the updated fiddle, I also fixed the opacity issue. Your whole overlay had `opacity: 0.8;` and that affects also all children of that overlay. Instead, you should use slightly transparent `background-color` in rgba notation for overlay:

```
background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.8);
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/ppqct0dg/4/

rgba uses decimal number, in contrast to `#cccccc` notation, which uses hexa-decimal numbers.

Comment: thanks for your help... it is working now as I wanted :)

Comment: Glad I could help. But: You still haven't marked the answer.